# How to redraw a TextView after using setVisibility(View.GONE);

Tags: android, textview, visibility, onscroll

i`m wondering how to recreate a view after using view.GONE on it.
I need to make a textview disappear on scrolling down, and come back after scrolling up. I guess i should find it first, and then what?
Thnx!
Here is my code (using Fragment):

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if (view.getId() == listView.getId()) {
        final int currentFirstVisibleItem = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();

        if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
           TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

                //what goes here?
        }

        mLastFirstVisibleItem = currentFirstVisibleItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: simply with View.VISIBLE....

Comment: it won`t work, after GONE. It works only after INVISIBLE.

Comment: GONE means only, that the view is not taking any space in the layout, INVISBLE means, the view takes space eg. the place for the view is just empty, but taken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`. Try this way.

```
if (currentFirstVisibleItem > mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (currentFirstVisibleItem < mLastFirstVisibleItem) {
       TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give

```
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```